# Настройка apache 2.0.64 и PHP 5.2.17

Tags: apache, настройка, php

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с настройкой `Apache 2.0.64 и PHP 5.2.17`.Вот как я настраивал:

`htaccess`:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinksDirectoryIndex index.php
```

`httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache2.dll"  - когда подключаю не пашет Апач, когда                                                    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Выключаю - работает.
Жду ответа, большое спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте текст вопроса корректно, а то каша какая-то получается...Попробуйте поставить [XAMPP][1]  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую, хотя бы изредка, читать документацию: как прикручивать 5 PHP ко второму Апачу в intall.txt подробно написано.

Даю конспект:

- Забыть про htaccess и писать DirectoryIndex в httpd.conf (в "Main server config" части)

`<IfModule dir_module>`

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

`</IfModule>`

- Писать **полностью** все требуемые директивы для PHP

`PHPIniDir "C:/php5/"`

`LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache2.dll"`

`AddType application/x-httpd-php phtml php`